# Removing modifier error

Tags: grammaticality, ambiguity, relative-clauses, modifiers

The modifier error in the sentence below creates ambiguity regarding who is on the way home - John or the huge man.

> John saw a huge man on his way home

What are the different ways to fix this? The intended meaning could be either - John or the huge man.

> 1. John saw a huge man **who** was on his way home

Who introduces a relative clause that necessarily applies to what immediately precedes it (the huge man).
So this seems fine.

> 2. John saw a huge man while he was on his way home

This seems to retain the ambiguity.

> 3. John saw a huge man while on his way home

Note: There are various of phrasing this correctly (as pointed out in some of the answers), but I am interested in verifying the correctness (or otherwise) of the version above.
It seems correct, referring to John, but I can't justify why?

Comment: I'd say that the reading of (2) is rather that it was John who was on his way home, and that (3) just reflects this in a deleted version. You don't say 'I saw a man while he was on his way home' (with saw = noticed).

Comment: _On his way home, John saw a huge man_. Placing the clause 'on his way home' next to 'John' removes the ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming John is the person who is going home, you can so phrase your sentence that it will convey what you mean it to, without ambiguity.

> - When he was on his way home, John saw a huge man.
> - As John was going home, he saw a huge man.
> - John was on his way home when he saw a huge man.