# Ambiguity in assigning a clause to one of the two preceding clauses

Tags: sentence, phrasing

Consider the sentence:

> We use a transmitter to communicate with a device that is placed in the package using a new technology.

Here, the part *"using a new technology"* applies to *"We use a transmitter to communicate with a device"* -> *We use a transmitter to communicate with a device using a new technology.*

However, could it sound like *"The device is placed in the package using a new technology"*?

If so, how to avoid the ambiguity in the phrasing?

Comment: We communicate with a device that is placed in the package with a transmitter that uses a new technology.

Comment: I'd say your first analysis of your original sentence isn't accurate;  'using a new technology' may modify 'We use a transmitter to communicate with a device that is placed in the package' or .... //// Using a new technology, we use a transmitter to communicate with a device that is placed in the package. //// We use a transmitter to communicate with a device that (using a new technology) is placed in the package. or We use a transmitter to communicate with a device that is placed, using a new technology, in the package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing modifier error](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/428493/removing-modifier-error)

Comment: Note that the attachment ambiguity is compounded by the fact that _use a transmitter to communicate_ can be a constituent all by itself, leaving _with a transmitter_ as an instrumental adjunct instead of a complement governed by _communicate_. This happens long before one reaches _using a new technology_, and produces many more possible parses.

Comment: _Using a new technology, we communicate, by transmitter, to a device that is placed in the package._